# Differenciate types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types

I was thinking about a good solution how to differenciate between types when a function can return two different types. As an example, I currently develop something for Excel where I get data from an Office API.

This data as string can be different based on whether is a "Cell" or a "CellRange".

For example purposes, I have replaced the actual logic to `this.checkSomething` which doesn't change the question.

```
detectCoordinateOrCell(adress: string): CellRange|Cell {
    if (this.checkSomething(address)) {
      return new CellRange(adress);
    } else {
      return new Cell(adress);
    }
}
```

How would you then usually check those types after receiving some object from this `detectCoordinateOrCell` method?

- add some helper method?
- make everywhere an if/else
- in class (Cell/CellRange)?
- or something completly different

I try to achive cleaner code and better code design. I know there might be not just exact one solution for that, but you may know more about Typescript than I know.

Comment: You could return CellRange with one element or check later in code using `instanceof` keyword

Comment: teoreticaly you are possible to create custom conditional type. but it depends on what this.checkSomething is doing... if you are able to make conditional type based on "address" parameter than typescript would infer return type for you...

Comment: @JurajKocan Really cool, didn't know about conditional types, but it sounds pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
address instanceof CellRange
address instanceof Cell